# chrome debugger skipping breakpoints, extension development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out how to develop extensions in chrome and started out with the obvious: adblock plus.

But I noticed something very unsettling: the break points get skipped.

[image]

As you can see, I set a break point on the line `console.log("Was here 00 " +  timeStamp());` but the message was still printed to the screen.

I expect the Javascript interpreter to break on the break points. Obviously it's not happening.

I don't understand this. Can someone please shed some light on this mystery?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Is it possible that it's because the machine is very slow?

Comment: please upload your manifest as well

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure why the breakpoint is not always getting hit, but I suspect it could be some timing issue with the JS engine. It would be interesting to find out for sure. I found a workaround that should help anyway:

1. Add a `debugger` statement where you had the logging call. This always gets hit. It's in the code, so there's no issue with timing.
2. On the line below where you will have the logging call, add a [Conditional Breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints) by right clicking on the line number and selecting "Add conditional breakpoint...". Instead of using an actual condition, just inject the console statement.

   For example, `console.log("The time is " + new Date());`

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Now when you load a page, the debugger will break at the `debugger` statement, and then once you continue execution, the console log will occur.

[image: console Log]